# What optimizations can a C++ compiler perform that a C compiler cannot?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization

I've somehow implanted in my head the idea that a C++ compiler can perform certain optimizations that a C compiler cannot. I (think I) remember hearing this in a conference talk, perhaps regarding the use of C++ in embedded programming.

If I recall correctly, I think these optimizations had to do with the idea that you can qualify the use of pointers (and other means of indirection, like references) with more information at compile-time.

For instance, "const" is an example of such a compile-time human-supplied tag available both C and C++. Is there similar information that only C++ has?

Some things that spring to mind are the different types of iterators and their requirements, but I'm not sure if that allows for C++ to make some optimizations.

EDIT: I think the talk I had in mind was [Dan Saks's cppcon 2016 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Sd8A6_fYU), but I realize now that (from what I understand) he mainly mentions how C++'s type system allows for better compile-time type-checking.

I think some of the examples I would enjoy hearing more about are things closer to how C++'s `std::sort` can be optimized more readily than C's `qsort` (thanks to multiple commenters). Explanations to when this sort of scenario occurs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: C++ compiler can optimise C++ programs. A C compiler cannot, because it cannot compile C++ programs at all.

Comment: Templates enable for easier inlining. i.e. `std::sort` is very likely to outperform `qsort` due to `qsort` taking a hard-to-optimise function pointer. I can't really think of anything else though. Plus yeah, what eerorika said.

Comment: Ah yes! `qsort` vs `std::sort` I think was one of these prime examples because of the function pointer. I think any casts to `void *` likewise destroy optimizations?

Comment: C++ `std::sort` versus C `qsort` is often brought up.

Comment: If you just consider the C intersection of C++, then I suspect the optimizations available are the same.  (Assuming the same vendor's compiler for both C and C++.)

Comment: @Eljay I would say there is no *C subset* of C++. One might think about "intersection".

Comment: @Eljay But remember that there be dragons in that subset. There exist code that is both valid C and valid C++, yet have different semantics. The "C subset" of C++ is not as simple as it may seem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. • fair enough.  Corrected!

Comment: rvalue references and move semantics come to mind. But they won't affect a C program.